# Getting MathJax working on an angular cli project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, mathjax

I would like to be able to use MathJax on my @angular/cli project. I previously had an Angular 2 project that used systemjs where this was not a problem. angular cli switched to using webpack, however, and I can't seem to get this new project working.

I believe I followed all the instructions for global library installation as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#global-library-installation), but it's possible I'm misunderstanding something.

I built a repo that demonstrated what's happening. It can be seen [here](https://github.com/pbarringer3/math-bug).

Basically, what I've done is install @angular/cli and set yarn as its default package manager.

I started the project with

```
ng new math-bug
```

I installed dependencies with

```
yarn add express body-parser mathjax mongoose
yarn add @types\mathjax --dev
```

I modified the file .angular-cli.json, adding the following to the scripts array (previously empty).

```
"../node_modules/mathjax/MathJax.js"
```

I added a component to my project that uses the line:

```
"MathJax.Hub.Queue([ "Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.id]);"
```

But when I try to build my project with ng build, I get the following error:
When I build my project I get the error:

```
ERROR in C:/Users/Pat/ProgrammingProjects/math-bug/src/app/latex/latex.component.ts (23,9): Cannot find name 'MathJax'.
C:/Users/Pat/ProgrammingProjects/math-bug/src/app/latex/latex.component.ts (23,40): Cannot find name 'MathJax'.
```

Extra information if it's helpful - I'm running this on Windows 10 and when I run ng --version, this is the output:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.2.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler: 4.0.1
@angular/core: 4.0.1
@angular/forms: 4.0.1
@angular/http: 4.0.1
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.2
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.1
@angular/router: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
```

Comment: This fixed some of my problems but MathMenu.js and MathZoom.js extensions cannot be found how did you go around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `src/tsconfig.app.json` add `mathjax` to `types` as follows:

`"types": ["mathjax"]`

if you also plan on using `mathjax` for testing add the same thing to `src/tsconfig.spec.json`

Read here on `types`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my problem!

Comment: This fixed some of my problems but MathMenu.js and MathZoom.js extensions cannot be found how did you go around that?